# T-test for when groups are composed partly of the same respondents?

Tags: t-test

I have pre- and post-test data from two groups (n=12, n=17), where 12 of the participants in both groups are the same people. While I have codes to identify the participants of the post-test, due to an oversight, no identifying codes were collected during the pre-test. What are the ways in which I can analyse this data? Would it be okay to do a two-sample test?

Comment: You can do a calculation treating the groups as unpaired,  but neither you nor any reader has a good basis to interpret the results. Even if the means are about the same, you can't be sure that isn't a side-effect of who is in one test and not the other.  And the analysis is wrong if you don't respect the pairing that exists in principle for some people. Depends on what you want to do with this but as a Ph.D. supervisor, Ph.D. examiner, journal reviewer and journal editor I'd say that the analysis is unacceptable at Ph.D. or publication levels. Sorry, but no good news or rescue option.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Thanks for the reply.